# Can't add mongodart in a flutter file which contains a StatefulWidget

Tags: android, mongodb, dart, flutter, mongo-dart

I'm certainly the first to ask this question because I found just nothing on the internet about this issue. When I try to import `mongodart` in the main file of my flutter application, I got this error in my IDE (VsCode) and also when I try to run the project with `flutter run`:

> The name 'State' is defined in the libraries 'framework.dart' and
>   'mongo_dart.dart'.

more:

> Compiler message: lib/main.dart:37:32: Error: Expected 0 type
>   arguments. class _MyHomePageState extends State {
>                                  ^ lib/main.dart:34:20: Error: The return type of the method 'MyHomePage::createState' is
>
> ## lib1::_MyHomePageState, which does not match the return type of the overridden method (#lib2::State<#lib2::StatefulWidget>). Change to a
>
> subtype of #lib2::State<#lib2::StatefulWidget>.   _MyHomePageState
>   createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
>                      ^ file:///home/quentin/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1:
>   Error: This is the overridden method ('createState').
>   lib/main.dart:41:5: Error: Method not found: 'setState'.
>       setState(() {
>       ^^^^^^^^ lib/main.dart:41:5: Error: The method 'setState' isn't defined for the class '#lib1::_MyHomePageState'. Try correcting the
>   name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named
>   'setState'.
>       setState(() {
>       ^ lib/main.dart:63:25: Error: Getter not found: 'widget'.
>           title: new Text(widget.title),
>                           ^^^^^^ lib/main.dart:63:25: Error: The getter 'widget' isn't defined for the class '#lib1::_MyHomePageState'. Try
>   correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a
>   getter or field named 'widget'.
>           title: new Text(widget.title),

Note: The StatefulWidget is the one from the sample app.

I'm sure this problem is caused by `mongodart` because when I remove:

`import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart';`

any form of error disappear. [Here's](https://www.dropbox.com/s/in2dwwo8qr11p7d/code.dart?dl=0) the code that causes the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is class inside the mongo package named "State" which causes the conflict, you can use an alias for that package, like this.

```
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart' as mongo;
```

And if you want to access to any mongo_dart classes just use :

```
mongo.NameOfTheClass
```

Comment: OMG: how can developers in mongo_dart do something like this??? Thanks for help anyway!